# yahoo and AOL security update require mail ids to be sent as reply_to header which is not honored by gmail.Suggest workarounds

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail, yahoo-api

We have been trying to send the customer feedbacks posted on our website to a specific Gmail address so that it is attended and tracked. 
Earlier, we used to send this mails from our servers with customer's emails in the from address section. But due to latest security changes made by Yahoo and AOL(DMARC policy) we are forced to change this and send the customers emails in the reply_to headers. However, we learnt that gmail doesn't honor the reply_to header and expects mail ids to be sent over the from field.

We are using php codeigniter for this implementation. Can anybody please suggest a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to fix this by marking the customer's email ids in the cc field and sending it via our own mail address.